# Если бы вы могли сложить бумагу в 42 раза, она бы достигла Луны

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Емм.. данное утверждение нашел одном сайте.

Толщина бумажной страницы — 0,01 см. Значит, если сложить страницы друг на друга,
то нам понадобится 384 000 000 000 страницы, чтобы стопка доросла до Луны.

Решил попробовать это решить в коде.

```
public void Start()
{
    int count = 0;
    long distancetoMoon = 384000000000;
    long paper = 1;

    while (distancetoMoon > paper)
    {
        count++;
        paper += paper;

        Debug.Log("Количество слоёв - " + paper);
        Debug.Log("Количество действий - " + count);
    }
}
```

Что вышло

```
Количество слоёв - 2
Количество действий - 1
Количество слоёв - 4
Количество действий - 2
Количество слоёв - 8
Количество действий - 3
Количество слоёв - 16
Количество действий - 4
Количество слоёв - 32
Количество действий - 5
Количество слоёв - 64
Количество действий - 6
Количество слоёв - 128
Количество действий - 7
Количество слоёв - 256
Количество действий - 8
Количество слоёв - 512
Количество действий - 9
Количество слоёв - 1024
Количество действий - 10
Количество слоёв - 2048
Количество действий - 11
Количество слоёв - 4096
Количество действий - 12
Количество слоёв - 8192
Количество действий - 13
Количество слоёв - 16384
Количество действий - 14
Количество слоёв - 32768
Количество действий - 15
Количество слоёв - 65536
Количество действий - 16
Количество слоёв - 131072
Количество действий - 17
Количество слоёв - 262144
Количество действий - 18
Количество слоёв - 524288
Количество действий - 19
Количество слоёв - 1048576
Количество действий - 20
Количество слоёв - 2097152
Количество действий - 21
Количество слоёв - 4194304
Количество действий - 22
Количество слоёв - 8388608
Количество действий - 23
Количество слоёв - 16777216
Количество действий - 24
Количество слоёв - 33554432
Количество действий - 25
Количество слоёв - 67108864
Количество действий - 26
Количество слоёв - 134217728
Количество действий - 27
Количество слоёв - 268435456
Количество действий - 28
Количество слоёв - 536870912
Количество действий - 29
Количество слоёв - 1073741824
Количество действий - 30
Количество слоёв - 2147483648
Количество действий - 31
Количество слоёв - 4294967296
Количество действий - 32
Количество слоёв - 8589934592
Количество действий - 33
Количество слоёв - 17179869184
Количество действий - 34
Количество слоёв - 34359738368
Количество действий - 35
Количество слоёв - 68719476736
Количество действий - 36
Количество слоёв - 137438953472
Количество действий - 37
Количество слоёв - 274877906944
Количество действий - 38
Количество слоёв - 549755813888
Количество действий - 39
```

У меня получилось 39 на не 42. Что не так?

Comment: @Danis тут `paper` не толщину считает, а "количество страниц"

Comment: n1tr0xs, а разница? смысл не меняется.

Comment: по-хорошему должно получиться даже не `42`, а `41`, т.к. у вас изначально тут одна страница уже есть

Comment: Всё правильно @Danis написал, 2 нуля в расстоянии потерял

Comment: @JuniorOne тогда и переменную distancetomoon тоже надо делить )

Comment: У него расстояние в см

Comment: @SmorcIRL где вы тут видите переменную расстояния ? тут кол-во слоев, которое у нас "есть" и количество страниц (читай - слоев) которое нужно

Comment: главный вопрос - эти два высказывания взяты из одного источника ? (1- 42 раза, 2 - 384 и бла-бла)

Comment: Вообще, это возведение в степень. Сложить бумагу в 42 раза - это значит возвести 2 в степень 42. `Math.Pow(2, 42)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

расстояние до луны 384467 км. в сантиметрах это `384467 * 1000 * 100` = `38446700000` теперь надо умножить на сто и получаем число:

```
3 844 670 000 000
```

а у вас

```
384 000 000 000
```

что в десять раз меньше